# How to state sentences for KB ∧ ¬ α given existing KB?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How do I state the sentences for KB ∧ ¬ α when I already have KB.

KB:

∀xTourist(x) => Person(x): Every tourist is a person.

∀xTourist(x) ∧ visits(x, Malaysia) => walksCanopy(x): Every tourist who visits Malaysia walks the canopy.

∀xPerson(x) ∧ has(x, Acrophobia) => fallSick(x, walksCanopy): Every person who has acrophobia falls sick when they walk the canopy.

∃xPerson(x) => has(x, Acrophobia): There are some people who have acrophobia.

Friend(Abu, Bill): Abu and Bill are friends.

Person(Abu) => livesIn(Abu, Malaysia): Abu is a person who lives in Malaysia.

Person(Bill) => livesIn(Bill, Canada): Bill is a person who lives in Canada.

∀xFriend(x) ∧ Friend(Bill, x) ∧ visitsCountry(Bill, x): Bill visits the countries of all his friends.

has(Bill, Acrophobia): Bill has acrophobia.

Prove that "Bill will fall sick".

I already looked at my lecture notes and even looked it up online but I can't seem to understand what KB ∧ ¬ α is.

Thanks.

Comment: You need the formula $\alpha$.

Comment: Then you have to negate it and add to the four formulas of KB.

Comment: Having said that, maybe you can add detials about the problem you are working on...

Comment: Maybe you are working with Resolution ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hi, I've edited my question and changed my KB. If I am understanding it correctly α is "Bill will fall sick"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\text {KB}$ a set of sentences and $\alpha$ a sentence.

In order to prove that $\text {KB} \vDash \alpha$ we consider $\text {KB} \cup \{ \lnot \alpha \}$ and apply the [Resolution proof-procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_first_order_logic) for *predicate logic*.

If we succeed deriving the *empty clause*, we have shown that $\text {KB} \cup \{ \lnot \alpha \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, that is equivalent to $\text {KB} \vDash \alpha$.

---

In your example, you are asked to prove that "Bill will fall sick" is implied by $\text {KB}$.

This means that "Bill will fall sick" is "your $\alpha$" and thus you have to add "Bill will **not** fall sick" to $\text {KB}$.

Comment: So basically if I have to state my sentences for KB it'd be:


∀xTourist(x) => Person(x) ∧ ¬ fallSick(Bill): Every tourist is a person and Bill will not fall sick.


and so on. Is that right?

Comment: @MikeMann - Yes $\lnot \alpha$ is ¬ fallSick(Bill).

Comment: thanks! I'm gonna work on CNF conversion and resolution now and see if I can figure it out.